# Fail the unit tests when the database schema, and entity are changed, but unit tests are not changed

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

Following is the exact scenario in my application:

- There are several C# methods in the codebase which are using Entity
  framework to talk with SQL database.
- Unit tests are written against all methods, and covers all possible permutation and combinations based on method signature, input requirements, and return values.
- Unit tests are working fine, and are failing when they should (i.e., cases like some validation is changed or expected return value is changed, but unit tests are not reflected for the same).
- There are cases, where a developer performs a change in SQL schema, and updates the entity in the C# code. In this case, unit tests are passing which is absolutely fine because its just underlying logic is changed, but not the input, validations, or return value.
- However, I want some unit tests to be failed when the database schema and entity are changed, but unit tests are not changed. That means, I want developers to fix the unit tests when they change database schema and entity.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve the same?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code.

Comment: Are you unit-testing your database schema? If not, why do you need to tie the resulting functionality to an implementation detail?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I have given scenario details. let me know if you need more clarity over the same. I need approach not the code so I think there are some cases where you dont need code to support your question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - No, I am not unit-testing database schema. Is it the only possible way out? or if there something that we can fit into implementation?

Comment: This is what integration tests are for. Write a handful of tests that perform operations against an actual instance of the database.

Comment: My point was that tying your unit tests to an implementation detail is a sure way to create brittle tests. If you still get the expected outcome after a database refactoring, does it matter that the test was updated or not? Isn't one of the points of having good tests that you should be free to actually do refactoring and changes without affecting the outcome?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - yes, I agree with your point. The need of unit tests to fail is because the database is shared between two disconnected projects. So if a developer of one project changes the database schema, we want to alert them that this schema change should be reflected in other project as well.

Comment: How can your developers "fix" a unit test that doesn't fail (without you forcing it to fail)? What is there to fix?

Comment: Write tests for another project - and you done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I moved up this last paragraph because it appears to the the X of your [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I do suggest reading all other paragraphs because you seem to be misunderstanding what a unit test is, and what purpose it serves.*

### Unit tests do not test multiple codebases!

I just noticed this in the comment you wrote:

> So if a developer of one project changes the database schema, we want to alert them that this schema change should be reflected in other project as well.

Unit tests should not be used as a way to synchronize two otherwise completely unrelated codebases.

This is a simple application of DRY vs WET: if these application share the same database schema, the database schema (and related EF entities) should be in a **single** source which both applications depend on.
Don't develop the same thing twice because you end up with constantly having to sync one when the other changes (which is what you're dealing with now).

For example, you can host the "shared data" project on a Nuget server, and have both applications refer to that self-hosted Nuget packages. When confirgured correctly, whenever an application is built, it will fetch the latest version of the "shared data" project, thus ensuring that both applications always work with the latest version of the database schema.

A second way to do this (if you don't want to create a shared dependency) is to have your subversioning system observe certain files (e.g. the entity class folder) and alert you if any change is made in those files. When you receive an alert, you'll be aware to check if this change impacts the other application's codebase.
And if I understand you correctly, you're really just trying to get an alert, right?

There are other ways to solve this, and the decision depends on your infrastructure and what technologies your team uses. **But it should definitely not be done by manually scripting/faking unit test failures.**

---

### Don't forget the "unit" in "unit test"

> I want some unit tests to be failed when the database schema and entity are changed

Unit tests test **one** thing (hence "unit"). It seems like you're writing tests that test two things: the business logic and the database. That's an integration test. Just as a rule of thumb:

- Unit tests test **one** component.
- Integration tests test the interaction between **multiple** components.

---

### Don't test external dependencies

If you were to write a unit test for EF specifically (which you shouldn't, but more on that later), you would not actually involve an actual database in the test. At best, you'd assert the SQL that is generated by EF, without running that query on the database.

Repeating my point, unit tests test **one** component. Entity Framework and the database server are **two** different things.

When using external components (such as a database server), you are again delving into the realm of integration tests.

---

### Only test your own code

As mentioned before, you shouldn't be testing Entity Framework. Unit testing a library is basically doing the library developer's work. You shouldn't occupy yourself how a library works. If anything, you use a library specifically because you *don't* want to know how it works internally.

Consider this test:

```
public void TestForAddition()
{
    var expectedValue = 2;
    var testValue = 1 + 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(testValue,expectedValue);
}
```

What you're doing here is testing the `+` operator, which is provided by the C#.Net framework. That is not part of *your* code, and therefore you shouldn't be testing it. The idea is the same as the EF argument: it's not your code, and not up to you to test. You have to trust in the dependencies you use.

However, if you have overloaded the `+` operator, you should test that (because it's *your* code)

```
public static Person operator+ (Person a, Person b) 
{
   return new Person() { Name = a.Name + " " + b.Name };
}

public void TestForPersonAddition()
{
    var expectedValue = "Billie Jean";

    var billie = new Person() { Name = "Billie" };
    var jean = new Person() { Name = "Jean" };

    Assert.AreEqual(billie + jean,expectedValue);
}
```

What this means for your EF-centric example is that **you should not be unit testing Entity Framework**. You should only have unit tests for your code, not that of EF.
You can, however, write integration tests for this. And this can achieve what you want: you run the integration tests against an existing database. If the integration tests pass, you'll know that the new codebase is compatible with the existing database. If they don't, then you know an issue has occurred that warrants a developer's attention.

---

## Unit tests test behavior!

> However, I want some unit tests to be failed when the database schema and entity are changed, but unit tests are not changed. That means, **I want developers to fix the unit tests** when they change database schema and entity.

So you want your developers to fix unit tests that were never broken in the first place?

Your intention doesn't make sense to me. You've changed some code and the unit tests are not failing. That is a good thing. But you want to *make* them fail, so your developers are then forced to "fix" the unit tests (that weren't broken in the first place).

**If the unit tests pass and yet you still claim that there is something wrong in the behavior of the application, then your unit tests are not doing the job they're supposed to do**.

You're misusing unit tests. The issue isn't trying to figure out how to force unit tests to fail; the issue is what you're expecting a unit test's outcome to tell you.
Unit tests should not be used to test whether the internal system has changed. **Unit tests test whether the application still behaves the same way** (even if some of the code has changed).

If I rewrite your codebase from scratch, and then run the same (untouched) unit tests on my new codebase, and all unit tests pass, that means that **my code behaves the same way as yours** and our codebases are functional equivalents of each other (at least in regards to the behavior that you've written tests for)

---

Comment: Very nice and helpful information. Definitely there were some misconceptions from myside which brought me to this scenario. You have nicely explained, and clarified all the concepts about unit tests and integration tests. this will also be helpful to future readers referring to the post.